# How to Use External Python Files to Change the State of Vehicles in Veins？

Tags: python

I successfully used Veins to connect Sumo and Omnet++. I wanted to use external Python commands to modify the status of vehicles in Sumo. The problem I encountered was that when starting Sumo with Python, changing the status of vehicles can be displayed in Sumo, but it cannot be synchronized in Veins.

I'm wondering if this is because we started a sumo using external Python, but the veins connection was another sumo